# How can I migrate my toolboxes and styles from ArcGIS 9.x to 10.x?

Tags: arcgis-10.0, arcgis-9.3, migration

I am migrating from ArcGIS 9.3.1 to ArcGIS 10 SP4. I have several toolbox and style files that I want transfer to my new computer which is now running Windows 7. Can anyone tell me where I should put them?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Styles:**

Your **personal style** is the default location where new symbols and style elements are saved. It is empty to begin with but can be used to organize your style contents. It will always be referenced by ArcMap.

> **On Windows XP**, it is located at install drive:\Documents and Settings\\Application Data\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap.
>
> **On Windows Vista and Windows 7**, it is located at install drive:\Users\\AppData\Roaming\ESRI\Desktop10.1\ArcMap.

The **system styles** included with the software are read-only, indicated by a grey folder icon in the Style Manager dialog box. They are installed at **install drive:\Program Files\ArcGIS\Desktop10.1\Styles.** You can copy symbols and other style elements from them into writable styles to use as a starting point. Populated, writable styles have yellow folder icons; white folder icons indicate empty style folders.

http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s600000008000000

**Toolbox files** are locked in the default (installed location) this can only be changed via http://support.esri.com/en/knowledgebase/techarticles/detail/39256